# divide sum into the same column based on categories from another column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following dataset:

```
+-----------+-----+-----------+
|       date|count|steps_order|
+-----------+-----+-----------+
|2021-12-10 |    4|          2|
|2021-12-10 |   95|          2|
|2021-12-10 |   45|          4|
|2021-12-10 |  273|          4|
|2021-12-10 |    3|          4|
|2021-12-10 |  303|          1|
|2021-12-10 |   47|          1|
|2021-12-10 |    7|          1|
|2021-12-10 |  279|          3|
|2021-12-10 |   47|          3|
|2021-12-10 |    3|          3|
+-----------+-----+-----------+
```

I want to be able to divide the total sum of the count column between steps_order 1 and 2.

I tried this:

```
Completion Rate = 
DIVIDE(
    SUM('table'[count], FILTER( 'table', 'table'[steps_order]=1)),
    SUM('table'[count], FILTER( 'table', 'table'[steps_order]=2))
)
```

and other similar solutions but I'm always stuck with this error `The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to create a measure, you can use the following code:

```
Completion Rate = 
DIVIDE(
    Calculate(SUM('table'[count]), FILTER( 'table', 'table'[steps_order]=1)),
    Calculate(SUM('table'[count]), FILTER( 'table', 'table'[steps_order]=2))
)
```

You will get this result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is as a measure

```
Completion Rate =
    VAR Step_1 =
        CALCULATE (
            SUM ( 'table'[count] ),
            FILTER (
                ALL ( 'table'[count] ),
                'table'[count] = 1
            )
        )
    VAR Step_2 =
        CALCULATE (
            SUM ( 'table'[count] ),
            FILTER (
                ALL ( 'table'[count] ),
                'table'[count] = 2
            )
        )
    RETURN
        DIVIDE (
            Step_1,
            Step_2
        )
```

Comment: u need to use Calculate to filter data 
good blog post to read :
https://dax.guide/calculate/